# Better way to organize query methods in Android?

Tags: java, design-patterns, programming-practices, sqlite, crud

In my Android app I have:

1. A `SQLiteHelper` class that extends `SQLIteOpenHelper`, and takes care of things like table-creation and upgrades.
2. A `SQLiteDatasource` class that performs CRUD operations on the `SQLiteHelper` object.

However my `SQLiteDatasource` class is getting very bloated because it have so many methods. Lots of ways to apply CRUD to various types of objects and ways to view those objects, etc.

Is there a way to organize/refactor this better? Or do most people just organize them in some logical order and then explain the separations with comment lines? e.g. *"Open/close methods"*, *"ObjectA query methods"*, etc.

Comment: Have you thought about [using an ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) instead?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm mostly interested in what's considered good OOP/design practice for this situation (as opposed to using a third party tool that takes care of it for me)

Comment: Have you read GOF and Fowler?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Is GOF = Gang of Four = Design Patterns? If so, I have the book, but have not read it yet. Fowler I don't know what that is.

Comment: [Fowler](http://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature-ebook/dp/B008OHVDFM).

Comment: I'll have to pick this one up, thanks. What does it say about situations like these?

Comment: It says that using an ORM is considered a "best practice," if you're writing an actual, real-world application.

Comment: I use the repository pattern with a sqlite unit of work processor to great success. Have a look at it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Comment: Also using an ORM falls into the realm of not creating your own wheel, don't be afraid to use them as their drawbacks are just little performance cost and expressiveness (in some cases) only

Answer (score 1):

Use repository pattern. Create a repository class for each entity class in your app and put methods to manage that kind of entity there. That way you have clean separation and can take use of abstraction. I usually do something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T> {
    public T getById(long id){
       // query on SQLite
    }
     // etc. more common methods here
}
```

And repo for entity:

```
public class UsersRepository extends BaseRepository<UserEntity> {
     public long countAllAdministrativeUsers() {
          // query here
     }
     // othet user-specific database actions
}
```